# ¿Cómo obtener el % de la varianza explicada en un análisis dudi.hillsmith (PCA-MCA)?

Tags: r

He hecho una PCA-MCA de unas especies en base a 7 variables que aparecen en la base de datos llamada 'dadesQ' (algunas cuantitativas y otras cualitativas), con la función `dudi.hillsmith` (package `ade4`):

```
dd0 <- dudi.hillsmith(df=dadesQ, scannf = F, nf=2)
```

Para cada variable obtengo el % de varianza explicada en cada eje,

```
               RS1        RS2
var1      0.4754697 0.05399222
var2      0.6907877 0.65601387
var3      0.2770489 0.11814837
var4      0.4211996 0.03117113
var5      0.4912348 0.61195187
var6      0.1088027 0.05631116
var7      0.2100668 0.26775465
```

pero no consigo obtener el % de varianza explicado por esos dos ejes en total, es decir, un solo número. ¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más fácil de *consultarlo* es con `summary(objeto_dudi)`, donde `objeto_dudi` es el nombre del modelo que ajustaste. Y es consultarlo porque extrañamente el `summary()` no produce un output propiamente dicho, así que no podemos asignarle un nombre y conservarlo como una estructura de datos.

De todos modos es muy fácil extraer la información directamente desde el objeto `dudi.hillsmith`. La varianza explicada por un eje es el eigenvalor de ese eje como proporción de toda la varianza, es decir, de la suma de los eigenvalores. Entonces la obtendrías con `objeto_dudi$eig/sum(objeto_dudi$eig)`. Creo que en el ejemplo queda más claro.

```
library(ade4)
data("dunedata") #datos de ejemplo

objeto_dudi <- dudi.hillsmith(dunedata$envir, scann = FALSE, nf=2)

summary(objeto_dudi)
```

Muestra esto en pantalla, pero no hay forma de pasarlo a una estructura de datos. Usa la terminología "inercia proyectada". Es normal, hay pocos acuerdos de lenguaje en este campo y cada autor/a usa su propia nomenclatura. [Greenacre](http://www.grupobbva.com/TLFU/dat/DE_2008_practica_analisis_correspondencias.pdf) dice que

> ... podemos interpretar este porcentaje exactamente igual que, en regresión, explicamos el "porcentaje de varianza explicada". (p. 68)

```
Class: mix dudi
Call: dudi.hillsmith(df = dunedata$envir, scannf = FALSE, nf = 2)

Total inertia: 8

Eigenvalues:
  Ax1     Ax2     Ax3     Ax4     Ax5 
2.5421  1.8578  1.2306  0.9899  0.6927 

Projected inertia (%):
  Ax1     Ax2     Ax3     Ax4     Ax5 
31.776  23.222  15.383  12.374   8.658 

Cumulative projected inertia (%):
  Ax1   Ax1:2   Ax1:3   Ax1:4   Ax1:5 
31.78   55.00   70.38   82.76   91.41 

(Only 5 dimensions (out of 8) are shown)
```

Extraer los datos del modelo

```
varianza_explicada <- objeto_dudi$eig/sum(objeto_dudi$eig)

# Le agrego nombres para facilitar la lectura

names(varianza_explicada) <- paste0("Eje", 1:length(objeto_dudi$eig))

varianza_explicada

Eje1       Eje2       Eje3       Eje4       Eje5       Eje6       Eje7       Eje8 
0.31776060 0.23222407 0.15382594 0.12374192 0.08658363 0.05134938 0.02735787 0.00715659
```

Esto genera un vector con la varianza explicada por cada eje que se puede utilizar para incluirlo en tablas, gráficos, etc. Los resultados no son exactamente iguales al `summary()` porque son proporciones en lugar de porcentajes y no están redondeados.